# Why am I getting an error on cv2.seamlessClone?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to blend an image into a background and am following the tutorial by Satya Mallick at https://www.learnopencv.com/tag/seamless-cloning/. I am typing the exact same code and using the same images but am getting an error that states "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  vector::_M_default_append
Aborted (core dumped)"

I am using Python 3 and Open CV 4.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you downloaded the images with the appropriate sizes. For instance, the code works flawlessly if I download the [airplane with 320x207](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Japan.airlines.b777-300.ja733j.arp.jpg/320px-Japan.airlines.b777-300.ja733j.arp.jpg) and the [sky with 1024x574](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/23/Big_Tree_with_Red_Sky_in_the_Winter_Night.jpg/1024px-Big_Tree_with_Red_Sky_in_the_Winter_Night.jpg). However, it fails if the sky image is smaller (e.g., 800x449).